# Elasticsearch UpdateByQuery index refresh issue

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am working with Elasticsearch(ES) 5 and NEST 5 on C#

I have a workflow implemented using ES. Simplifiying the workflow has 2 steps.

Step 1: I generate the recipients for a message usin an UpdateByQuery statement base on some criteria.

Step 2: I query all recipients generated on step 1 to actualy deliver the message.

The problem I am facing is that some times the first step run so fast that when the second step runs the index is not refresh yet, so no recipient is found.

I tried setting "WaitForCompletion(true)" (default on Nest) but I get the same result. Also I notice that UpdateByQuery does not support refresh=wait_for so not sure how to do this.

My update by query looks like this:

```
query
.Index(allIndexesStr)

// Exclude all contact in this list
.Query(q =>
    ...
)
.WaitForCompletion(true)
// Update script
.Script(script => script
    .Inline(scriptStr)
    .Params(p =>
        ...
    )
)
.Routing(customerSiteId.ToString());
```

My search look like this:

```
search
.Index(allIndexesStr)
.Size(size)
.Scroll(timeout)
.Query(q =>
    ...
)
.Sort(sort => sort
    .Ascending("contactGuid.keyword")
)
.Routing(customerSiteId.ToString());
```

So I am wondering how is the propper way to solve this issue using ES...

Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in 2 steps then you should something like this

```
var result = ...
            .Index(allIndexesStr)

        // Exclude all contact in this list
        .Query(q =>
            ...
        )
        .WaitForCompletion(true)
        // Update script
        .Script(script => script
            .Inline(scriptStr)
            .Params(p =>
                ...
            )
        )
        .Refresh(true)
        .Routing(customerSiteId.ToString());

if (result.IsValid)
{
    search
    .Index(allIndexesStr)
    .Size(size)
    .Scroll(timeout)
    .Query(q =>
    ...
    )
    .Sort(sort => sort
        .Ascending("contactGuid.keyword")
    )
    .Routing(customerSiteId.ToString());
}
```